# how to create different objects with factory methods

Tags: c++

i gone through factory design pattern and got some doubt, 
 the code i have seen where in the `register` function,

they are storing the object in a `map` (*while registering, creating the objects first time and storing them in container class*), whenever we need the object we have to ask from the factory (`Factory::getObject("Rectangle")`), this rectangle is created and stored in the map already during registration, and this object they are returning whenever I am calling `getObject("Rectangle")`).

My doubt is every time I am getting same object only,
If I want to create 10 different objects for rectangle,

How can I create 10 diff objects of this rectangle?

Thanks in advanced.

```
RangeRingsFactory::RangeRingsFactory()
{
    Register("Big", &Picture::Create);            //picure & picyureInPicture inherited from IRangeRings 
    Register("Small", &PictureInPicture::Create);
}

RangeRingsFactory *RangeRingsFactory::Get()
{
    static RangeRingsFactory instance;
    return &instance;
}
void RangeRingsFactory::Register(const string &Name, CreateRRFn pfnCreate)
{
    map1[Name] = pfnCreate;
}

IRangeRings *RangeRingsFactory::CreateRR(const string &Name)
{
     FactoryMap::iterator it = map1.find(Name);
            if( it != map1.end() )
                   return it->second();
            return NULL;

}
```

picture :

```
Picture::Picture():IRangeRings()
{
    setRangeScale(QRect(-200,-200,400,400));
}
IRangeRings *Picture::Create()
{
    return new Picture();
}
```

main:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
    string Name1 = "Big";
    IRangeRings *p1 = RangeRingsFactory::Get()->CreateRR(Name1);
    string Name2 = "Small";
    IRangeRings *p2 = RangeRingsFactory::Get()->CreateRR(Name2);

    outerLayout = new QHBoxLayout;

    outerLayout->addWidget(p1);
    outerLayout->addWidget(p2);
    this->setLayout(this->outerLayout);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you have read only about the factory method..
May be it is mix of 2 or more design patterns..
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method this link might help you..

Comment: I think you just get a template object by `Factory::getObject`. You need create a new object by it. Can you add the link of `factory design pattern` that you mentioned in quest.

Comment: hai Alex Chi, i adited my post by ading the code, you could have a look, thanks.

Comment: Assumed the `PictureInPicture::Create` will return an object pointer of `PictureInPicture`. `p1` is a pointer of the `Picture` object. `p2` is a pointer of the `PictureInPicture` object. So `p1` is different with `p2`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're thinking of a combination of "prototype" and "factory" patterns.  The factory allows clients to "register" prototype instances, which may be subclasses of some common base.  Then the "getObject" method produces a copy of the requested prototype.

I did a quick Google for "prototype pattern c++"... Here are two of the many results:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Prototype

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185348/Prototype-Design-Pattern-2

Here's a simple example using a base class `shape` and two subclasses `rectangle` and `circle`.  These classes don't do much, but they have the minimum structure to illustrate the pattern.

*(Warning: I didn't actually compile this, so give me a break if I made any simple errors!)*

```
#include <map>

// Abstract base class for all shapes
class shape
{
public:
  virtual ~shape() {}
  virtual shape* clone() const = 0;
};

// Concrete subclass of shape
class rectangle : public shape
{
public:
  virtual shape* clone() const override
  {
    return new rectangle( *this );
  }
};

// Concrete subclass of shape
class circle : public shape
{
public:
  virtual shape* clone() const override
  {
    return new circle( *this );
  }
};

class Factory
{
public:
  // Add the given prototype object to the factory
  void register( std::string name, shape* proto )
  {
    protos[name] = proto;
  }

  // Get a copy of the prototype with the given name
  shape* getObject( std::string const& name ) const
  {
    // Warning: This will throw if name is not found!
    return protos[name]->clone();
  }

private:
  // Warning: This will leak unless cleaned up in the destructor!
  std::map<std::string, shape*> protos;
};

int main()
{
  Factory fact;
  fact.register( "rectangle", new rectangle() );
  fact.register( "circle", new circle() );

  // These will be separate copies of the original prototype
  shape* rect1 = fact.getObject( "rectangle" );
  shape* rect2 = fact.getObject( "rectangle" );

  // Don't leak!
  delete rect1;
  delete rect2;
}
```

Note: I know there are many ways to improve this code, but I tried to keep it simple to avoid distraction from the key points.

Answer (score 0):

The factory stores a map of strings to "creation functions."  In its constructor it registers two of them:  "Big" corresponds to `Picture::Create` and "Small" corresponds to `PictureInPicture::Create`.

The `CreateRR` method looks up the given `Name`, calls the corresponding creation function, and returns its result.

As long as both `Picture::Create` and `PictureInPicture::Create` both produce new objects, you will get a new object each time you call `CreateRR`.

So in fact you have...

- two **factory functions** - `Picture::Create` and `PictureInPicture::Create` - each of which always creates the same type of object
- one **factory class** - `RangeRingsFactory` - that hides the specific types from you (`Picture` and `PictureInPicture`) so you can simply ask for one by name ("Big" or "Small") without knowing or caring about the specific object type that is produced.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution A

It will have a different rect in IRangeRings, if you set a different rect when the `IRangeRings` is created.

Change these functions:

```
CreateRRFn()
IRangeRings *RangeRingsFactory::CreateRR(const string &Name)
IRangeRings *Picture::Create()
```

To:

```
CreateRRFn(QRect rect)
IRangeRings *RangeRingsFactory::CreateRR(const string &Name, const QRect &rect)
IRangeRings *Picture::Create(const QRect &rect)
```

Then use the instance of `RangeRingsFactory` to create new `IRangeRings` like this:

```
IRangeRings *p1 = RangeRingsFactory::Get()->CreateRR("Big", QRect(0, 0, 100, 100));
```

### Solution B

Also you can to add a new pure `virtual` function in `IRangeRings`, (I think the `IRangeRings` is a interface class), I named it as `ToSetRangeScale`.
And `Picture` and `PictureInPicture` must implement it:

```
void Picture::ToSetRangeScale(const QRect &rect) { setRangeScale(rect); }
void PictureInPicture::ToSetRangeScale(const QRect &rect) { setRangeScale(rect); }
```

Then call `ToSetRangeScale` to set the rect after create a object of `Picture` or `PictureInPicture`:

```
IRangeRings *p1 = RangeRingsFactory::Get()->CreateRR("Big");
p1->ToSetRangeScale(QRect(0, 0, 100, 100));
```

### At last

The `RangeRingsFactory` store some pointers of `Create` function. The same function can create the different object that has same class. The different function can create the different object that has different class. If you want change the property of the new object, you can set the property when the object is created, or after the object was created by new method.